# How to convert a LaTeX document whose bibliography uses more than one database using pandoc with citeproc?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, conversion, pandoc-citeproc

I'm using pandoc to convert some files created in LaTeX a couple of years ago to `.docx` format (yuk!). I've been going through this [blog entry](https://jabranham.com/blog/2016/11/using-pandoc-export-to-word/#fn:1) and apparently it's easy to do.

The hardest part had been passing the references, but `citeproc` seems to do well. I tried one of the documents and it worked out pretty well I think, except for the tables and the images.

Now, my problem is that I have several of the documents I have to convert into which the references are in more than one database and I don't know if pandoc with citeproc has a way to get the references from more than one database.

The statement:

```
pandoc my-document.tex --bibliography=library.bib -o my-document.docx
```

works pretty well.

getting back to the point, I have references like this:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,date=short,style=authoryear-ibid,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library1.bib}
\addbibresource{Library2.bib}
```

So my question comes down to: how can I convert a `LaTeX` file using `pandoc` with references like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple bibliographies with `--bibliography`:

```
pandoc my-document.tex --filter=pandoc-citeproc --bibliography=library1.bib --bibliography=library2.bib -o my-document.docx
```

Alternatively you could of course just merge the .bib files. Since they are simple text files, this should do:

```
cat library1.bib library2.bib > joinedlibrary.bib
```